# como poner el total de dos numeros en un Textfield, Sin BOTON

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jtextfield

Tengo **3 TextField**, 2 para colocar números y el tercero para poner el total de la suma de los anteriores. Pero no quiero colocar botones, sino que quiero que **al ingresar valores en los 2 primeros textfield me de automáticamente el resultado en el tercer textfield**. Agradezco de antemano

Comment: **JavaScript != Java**, y el IDE (Netbeans) nada tiene que ver con la pregunta. Lo que buscás entonces es mostrarlo a través de un evento...
Leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo utilizando eventos, que al presionar una tecla haga el calculo y asigne el valor al campo de resultado. Si colocas tu código puedo brindarte una respuesta mas específica y con código.

Answer (score 0):

Hola franco he logrado resolverlo de la siguiente manera espero te ayude.

private void jTextField2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

```
    Runnable miRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                
                String num1 = jTextField1.getText().toString();
                String num2 = jTextField2.getText().toString();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                int numero1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                int numero2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
                int resultado = numero1 + numero2;
                jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    Thread hilo = new Thread(miRunnable);
    hilo.start();
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).